# Binding in WPF and Silverlight - how does it actually work?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, inotifypropertychanged, dependencyobject

How does binding work under the hood in WPF and Silverlight?

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel objects and also used dependency properties on UI controls. Now, I am aware of the fact that the binding system will subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event and will update the UI whenever it is notified of changes in property. I want to know the internal working details of both approaches - implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and inheriting from `Dependency` object.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.  Your sentence "I am aware of the fact that the binding system will subscribe to PropertyChanged event and will update the UI whenever it is notified of changes in property." basically describes all of the magic.  Things that are *bindable* are DependencyProps on DependencyObjects.  Things that you bind *to* are on class that implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Why not use a disassembler (such as .Net Reflector or JetBrains dotPeek) and see for yourself?